# Как вывести список в строку через переменную (Python)?

Tags: python

```
str_list =[['some', 'special'],['text', 'for','you'],['-', 50]]
i = []
for i in str_list:
    
    for lis in i:

        print(lis)

Выводится в столбик:
some
special
text
for
you
-
50

А надо в строку:
some special text for you - 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую изучить формат команды `print`

В вашем случае нужно убрать перевод строки, заменив пробелом:
`print(lis, end = ' ')`